# superclass missing during xjc class generation;hierarchy inconsistency error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, xjc

I am a JAXB newbie. For a project, I was given the binding file with the xsd so that I can use the schema classes.
The Jaxb binding file(mainbindings.xjb) looks like this:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0">
   <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="main.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">  
      <jxb:globalBindings fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true" collectionType="com.example.Impl" choiceContentProperty="false" typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName" enableFailFastCheck="false" generateIsSetMethod="true" underscoreBinding="asWordSeparator">
         <xjc:serializable uid="100"/>
         <xjc:superClass name="com.example.mySuperClass"/>
         <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xsd:dateTime" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime" printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime"/>
      </jxb:globalBindings>
   </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I generated the classes using without xjc compiler errors:

**xjc -b mainbindings.xjb -b main.xsd -extension**

From this site, I learn that the compiler doesn't generate the superclass:
http://blog.frankel.ch/customize-your-jaxb-bindings

However, when I copy these classes under an eclipse project, I see the following error on most every class:
 **The hierarchy of the type  is inconsistent**

I googled for this error and found from this site (http://java.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Inconsistent_hierarchy) that if the superclass doesn't exist then this error pops up.
I tried a refresh as suggested here but the errors still exist.

Also, if the xjc doesn't generate a superclass, how else can this be resolved without me manually creating a random superclass?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extension is intended to have your generated classes extend an existing class.  You will need to provide this class. BTW - How are you currently trying to use this extension?

Comment: I gave the command exactly as above. Without the extension parameter, I had errors. Perhaps I didn't get your question? Do I understand that I have to be given this superclass, so I can use it with a classpath parameter for the xjc compiler to generate all the classes which extend this superclass??

Comment: What about the collectionType class in the global bindings attribute? should I also have such a class or will it be generATED?

Comment: @user907810 - You will need to have that class as well.  If you don't have the classes specified in the bindings file, then you may want to remove the corresponding entries.  They aren't required to generate a model.  They are just customizations to affect how a model is generated.

Comment: what about the class mentioned in the collectionType? I called up our customer who also said I dont need the superclass. what is the command to compile? is it the same one as above? also can I do it on eclipse instead of command line?

Comment: @user907810 - The following should help (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html), also if you are using Eclipse Juno Java EE edition you can `right click` on an XML schema and then `Generate` | `JAXB Classes...`.